# Questions regarding graph values

Tags: functions

Use the graph of f to determine each of the following. where applicable, use interval notation.

[image]

- a. the zero(s) of $f$ (type integer or decimal, commas where needed)
- b. what is $f(-1)$?
- c. what is the value of $x$ for which $f(x) = 4$?
- d. if $f(4)$ positive or negative?

Thank you so much!

... my bad.. I did not know I was supposed to edit my question.

OK.. so I would think that where f(x) = 4, x would equal 2, and f(4) is positive?

Comment: You have no idea where to start? What do you know?

Comment: Well I know that the zeros of a function are the x values where f(x)=0... I I believe that would be -1.5, 5.5

Comment: is that correct? Also, I thought f(-1) would be 1?

Comment: So far, so good.

Comment: That's good progress. Keep in mind though you're supposed to write about your progress in your question itself - it's generally not considered optional, and not accepted merely in the comments section. At any rate, now what are you thinking for parts (c) and (d)?

Comment: hi sorry I didn't realize.. I have updated the post. :)

Comment: Hi there.. I haven't heard from anyone .. is the last update to my post the correct answer please?